# Handling link in popup through selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, popup

I m trying to enter into the home page of this website. While I am doing so I am being blocked by a popup where there is a link which I need to click. Only then I can enter. I was able to handle until popup by using below code, but could not handle on how to click that link which appears in popup. That popup is not browser based. Can any one help me. Attached is the code for your reference

```
package com.certipath;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class handlingPopupAlert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        File file = new File("C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());      
        WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Opens web page
        driver.get("https://staging.trust-test.local/Home");

        // Switching to Alert        
        Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();

       // Capturing alert message.    
        String alertMessage=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();

       // Displaying alert message      
        System.out.println(alertMessage);
```

Comment: what is the outcome of System.out.println(alertMessage);?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to print out the alertMessage, then the way to dismiss it is to simply do:

```
alert.accept()
```

Hope this helps.

If this is not what you are looking for, please share an image of how the Popup looks like.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Here is the image of the alert. Its a certificate popup. I am still figuring out on how to click more choices hyper link in this image